# C# Modbus/tcp - hanging connection

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, modbus

I have written Windows service, which perform Modbus WriteMultipleRegisters function  call over TCP using [NModbus](https://code.google.com/p/nmodbus/) library to 3-party devices every 10 minutes (ticks of System.Threading.Timer).

Occasionally this connection hang up open usually during network problems. As the device accepts only one Modbus connection at time and others are refused, connection during all next ticks fail with SocketException - ConnectionRefused.

But the device automatically closes connections which don't respond after short time. Something must keep connection open at my side even for two days. What's more when my Service is restarted, everything is fine again. So there is definitely some forgotten open connection. But I didn't manage to reproduce this bug in dev, so I don't where/when.. connection hang up. I only know that next connection is refused.

I do the modbus function call with this part of code:

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(device.ip, 502))
    {
    using (Modbus.Device.ModbusIpMaster master = Modbus.Device.ModbusIpMaster.CreateIp(client))
          {
          master.WriteMultipleRegisters(500, new ushort[] { 0xFF80 });
    }  
}
```

device.ip is string containing IP address of device - it's correct, confirmed from SocketException details.

As I'm using using statement dispose is called on both objects.
I have looked trough NModbus source code and everything is disposed correctly.

Any idea how its possible that with this code connection is not closed?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that `.Dispose` is supposed to close the connection? I've run into that issue with another network library. It might just clean up resources without actually "shutting down" anything.

Comment: Yes, I have followed .Dispose call trough library and TcpClient.Dispose is called. NModbus uses unme library for disposing (file: https://code.google.com/p/unme/source/browse/trunk/src/Unme.Common/DisposableUtility.cs)

Comment: `Shutdown` and `Dispose` are two very different methods. `Shutdown` sends a "we're done" message to the other end while `Dispose` isn't always guaranteed to do so. Also, separate from any C# issues, don't forget that TCP connections aren't actually closed until a timeout expires (to prevent any data hanging in the internet infrastructure from being delivered to a newly opened connection on the same port). It's quite important to handle a graceful shutdown, since any lingering TCP connections can take 2-4 minutes to actually close, which can actually stall the .NET finalizer queue...

Comment: @Luaan Shutdown? I don't see any method of that name in TcpClient doc and its source code and VS don't recognized it too. Maybe you meant Close method, but Close is just alias to Dispose (details in comment to ZaXa ansver) But thanks for info about TCP connection closing.

Comment: Are you using multi-threading?

Comment: Beside ticks of timer I don't use multi-threading

Answer (score 4):

I agree with nemec.  If you review the documentation for [TcpClient.Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.dispose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if does not specifically mention closing the connection.  It frees managed and unmanaged resources by default, but it may not correctly tear down the connection.

Try changing your code to:

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(device.ip, 502))
{
    try 
    {
        using (Modbus.Device.ModbusIpMaster master = Modbus.Device.ModbusIpMaster.CreateIp(client))
        {
            master.WriteMultipleRegisters(500, new ushort[] { 0xFF80 });
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        // Log exception
    }
    finally 
    {
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

That way you are doing a clean close before dispose and it should clean up even if the Modbus protocol throws some kind of exception.

Comment: Maybe doc isn't clear about that, but I looked using ILSpy (http://ilspy.net/) to System.Net.TcpClient source code and Close is just alias for Dispose, because it beside logging only call Dispose. Than only in Dispose is everything including Socket and NetworkStream disposed/released/closed...

Comment: According to the docs it's not just an alias.  "The Close method marks the instance as disposed and requests that the associated Socket close the TCP connection. Based on the LingerState property, the TCP connection may stay open for some time after the Close method is called when data remains to be sent. There is no notification provided when the underlying connection has completed closing.
Calling this method will eventually result in the close of the associated Socket and will also close the associated NetworkStream that is used to send and receive data if one was created."

Comment: Are you using the same .NET runtime in the deployed version as the development version?  You mentioned you didn't see it in development.

Comment: Code have always true about behaviour of class. Documentation means nothing for running of code. Documentation is not very good written for these methods. Source code of methods: http://pastebin.com/2wE0QCiY.
Yes, but bugs connected with network are hard to reproduce.

Comment: I am basically out of ideas then.  But as for diagnostics, have you tried verifying that your app is holding the socket open?  Possibly using [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

did you play with TcpClient.LingerState Property

defualt setting could cause problems with resetting winsock

check it out
http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.lingerstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: No, I didn't modify this property

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but a comment with code.  We have this same issue on some of our installed computers, but not all of them.  The issue itself is also very intermittent, sometimes going months without happening.  I am hoping someone can find an answer.  Here is our brute force destroy / reconnect code that **does not work**:

```
        try
        {
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    // Close the stream
                    var stream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
                    if (stream != null)
                        stream.Close();
                }
                catch { }

                try
                {
                    // Close the socket
                    if (_tcpClient.Client != null)
                        _tcpClient.Client.Close();
                }
                catch { }

                // Close the client
                _tcpClient.Close();
                _tcpClient = null;
            }
            catch { }

            if (_device != null)
            {
                _device.Dispose();
                _device = null;
            }
        }
        catch { }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```